# SapUI5 Router Issue With XML Views

Tags: sapui5

I'm developing a simple UI5 project be able to learn how Router works.. In that process I'm faced with an issue related to Router events. I've three XML view which names are FirstPage, SecondPage and ThirdPage. The ThirdPage is implemented inside the other two pages as following code;

```
<mvc:XMLView viewName="SapUI5Tutorial.Application.Main.views.ThirdPage.view.ThirdPage"/>
```

For example FirstPage.xml

```
<mvc:View displayBlock="true" controllerName="SapUI5Tutorial.Application.Main.views.FirstPage.controller.FirstPage"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns="sap.m" height="100%">
<Page title="First Page" class="sapUiNoContentPadding">
    <subHeader>
        <Toolbar>
            <VBox width="100%" alignItems="Center">
                <Button text="Second Page Link" press="handleNavSecondPage"/>
            </VBox>
        </Toolbar>
    </subHeader>
    <mvc:XMLView viewName="SapUI5Tutorial.Application.Main.views.ThirdPage.view.ThirdPage"/>
</Page>
```

When I click "Second Page Link" button I'm navigating to SecondPage. But the ThirdPage is due to inside of SecondPage ThirdPage's Router function is running twice

ThirdPage's controller;

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
], function (Controller, FragmentController) {
"use strict";
var base, oRouter;
return Controller.extend("SapUI5Tutorial.Application.Main.views.ThirdPage", {
    onInit: function () {
        base = this;
        base.getView().setModel(oModel);
        oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(base);
        oRouter.getRoute("FirstPage").attachMatched(base.firstPagePatternMatched, base);
        oRouter.getRoute("SecondPage").attachMatched(base.secondPagePatternMatched, base);
    },
    firstPagePatternMatched: function (oEvent) {
        console.log(oEvent)
    },
    secondPagePatternMatched: function (oEvent) {
        //Due to the third page is used for inside two other pages (FirstPage and SecondPage) this function is running twice
        console.log(oEvent)
    }
});
```

});

How can I prevent running twice that Router event of ThirdPage ? Thank you for your helps

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the Thirdpage view inside of the first page, you need not have another patternMatched function for the ThirdPage.

Morover, I don't see a need of having a separate controller for the ThirdPageView. You can and should reuse the parent FirstView's controller.

Comment: You're right but when I turn back to the first page third page's init function is not triggered (Init function not working. It's triggering only once) Because it has already loaded before. How to trigger again to the Init function of ThirdPage ?

Comment: does this help? 
sap.ui.getCore().byId("ThirdPageViewId").getController().onInit();

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is with using `.attachMatched` instead of `.attachPatternMatched`

The former fires for any route or subroute whereas the latter fires for only the subroute.

The documentation is not very clear on this but can be found [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Route/methods/attachPatternMatched).